# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a non-nil UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, exc-bad-access

**EDIT:** This appears to be a Swift or Cocoapods bug. The `LinePlot` is defined in a Cocoapod.  When I inject my framework code directly into my project, everything is normal.

**EDIT 2:** At `configure`, my `plotPoints` array only has one value(seen in debugger)!  What could be happening?  Again, copy-pasting my framework code and using that new object works fine, my array has its values.

I get a bad access when calling a method on a custom UIView (LinePlot). The view is presented O.K. and is allocated O.K., but calling this method produces the error.

I have tried using the debugger and examining the tableViewCell's instance data.

```swift
let customView = LinePlot()

public func configure<ViewDataModel>(model withViewData: ViewDataModel) {
        guard let viewData = withViewData as? StockPlotViewData else {
            fatalError("Wrong type sent to StockPlotCell")
        }

        contentView.addSubview(customView)
        backgroundColor = .blue
        setupCustomView()

        let plotPoints: [CGPoint] = viewData.points.map { (doublePoint) -> CGPoint in
            let (x,y) = doublePoint
            return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        }

        customView.configure(withViewData: plotPoints, fillColor: .clear, graphLineWidth: 5.0)
    }
```

I expect the 'LinePlot' to be allocated and its methods able to be safely called. However, I get the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10c35e750)
```

on line

```
        customView.configure(withViewData: plotPoints, fillColor: .clear, graphLineWidth: 5.0)
```

Comment: I would move your 'let plotPoints' to just under your `guard` statement. Then, wrap everything below that in `DispatchQueue.main.async { all your UI stuff }`. I suspect you're updating off the main queue. You could debug that by adding a breakpoint where you're presently getting the error and see if you're on the main queue (should be thread 0).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried this and I get the same error.  I can't imagine that it's not a bug, because when I copy-paste my framework code in a new file, instantiate that new class, and use it the same way, everything works as expected. Edit: For clarification, `configure` is called in `cellForRowAt`, which I'm guessing is on the main thread (honestly, I'm not sure).

Comment: Oh, never mind.  Now I'm certain.  I glanced over the breakpoint advice. it's on the main thread.